# Python module not working after logging out

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I'm having some strange problems running some molecular dynamics simulations on a computing cluster. My simulations use a system called hoomd-blue, which I have compiled from source on the cluster.

After logging out and logging back in to the cluster, I find that the jobs I submit using hoomd-blue fail to start, giving the following error:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_hoomd)

I encountered a similar problem yesterday, which I fixed by just recompiling hoomd-blue. However this takes a significant amount a time and can't be done every day.

The python script still works on the machine used for submitting jobs to the cluster.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of computing cluster you are using- this covers a wide variety of setups and it will be difficult to diagnose the issue with so little information.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to this. Since I'm not sure what would be the most useful information, here's the website for the cluster: https://confluence.columbia.edu/confluence/display/rcs/Yeti+-+Technical+Information

Comment: What duration of time is between the logout/login? Where are you placing the modules once you have compiled them? Is this location available from all nodes on the cluster? Is it in the $PATH for all nodes on the cluster or does your job alter PYTHONPATH to include the compiled module?

This may also seem like a dumb question but have you spoken to your local support team at columbia?